# iReport issue with isStretchWithOverflow

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Currently I use the attribute ***isStretchWithOverflow*** to break the lines when the content in text field is too long. It works. But I want to know how can I determine the way it  breaks lines.

Below is the snippet of my *jrxml* file:

```xml
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" width="150" height="20"/>
    <box leftPadding="15">

    </box>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{content}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

For the content like

```
oh my god test="longstring" abcdefg hijk
```

I want "longstring" is regarded as a word. So my imagine output is

```
oh my god test=
"longstring" abcdefg
hijk
```

But the actual output is

```
oh my god test="
longstring" abcdefg
hijk
```

Another problem is similar

The original content is

```
abc.def/hij/k.lmnopqrstu
```

I want

```
abc.def/
hij/k.
lmnopqrstu
```

But the actual output is

```
abc.
def/hij/k.
lmnopqrstu
```

It does not break the line when it meet "/"

Is there any way I can do what I want?

Comment: It is seems to me that the ***net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer*** implementation (of ***net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRMeasuredText*** interface) class determines this behavior. You can look at its source code

Answer (score 1):

The net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer implementation (of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRMeasuredText interface) class uses the java.text.BreakIterator interface as implemented by the private RuleBasedBreakIterator class. The RuleBasedBreakIterator reads a file supplied with the JDK that defines the characters on which to perform line breaks on. Since the RuleBasedBreakIterator class is private I have not found an easy way to change the default behavior. Replacing net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer with an alternate implementation is possible by modifying the following properties:

```
#Default text measurer
net.sf.jasperreports.text.measurer.factory=default
net.sf.jasperreports.text.measurer.factory.default=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurerFactory
```

This in practice may not be advisable unless you can implement the robust breaking logic in the JDK with your customizations.

An alternative for some may be to use IBM JDK that does not ICU4J that provides a customizable implementation of RuleBasedBreakIterator as decsribed here:

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/05/tokenizing-text-with-icu4js.html