# JasperReports: Prevent textField to split on space or hyphen

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a JasperReports template that contains a textField element that will contain a variable length of strings. If the string is too long to fit the width, it'll be split which is fine except when the string contains a hyphen or a space char. In this case the string is split from that char. Below are some example of what's the input, observed outcome and wanted outcome + summary to make my point easier to understand.

```
input      observed   wanted   summary
_____________________________________
overflow  -> overfl -> overfl : OK
over flow -> over   -> over f : NOT OK
over-flow -> over-  -> over-f : NOT OK
```

Setting the reportElement to have isStretchWithOverflow="true" attribute will split the text on two lines, but this is not wanted behaviour.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: The input data comes from an external source, so I cannot directly change that. I ran some tests and noticed that using non-breaking space will do for spaces. non-breaking hyphen on the other hand is not printed at all, i.e. text 'over-flow' becomes 'overflow'. Not quite what is wanted.

Despite the input source not in my control, I could fix this problem by writing a Scriptlet that'll change spaces to non-breaking spaces and hyphens to non-breaking hyphens, only if those darn non-breaking hyphens would be printed.

Printing to PDF by the way, in case that gives some hints of the problem.

Comment: You question is the same as [iReport issue with isStretchWithOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174751/ireport-issue-with-isstretchwithoverflow)

Comment: @Alex K, not quite the same, I don't want the text to split on multiple lines. I just want it to end. Looking at the sources was my next options, the other post gives a good hint on where to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a font issue. Non-breaking hyphen works(\u2011) fine, when the font supports it. See fonts sample on how load other than the default font (DejaVu Sans for example).

If anyone has a better option for the input source modification than the Scriptlet, please let me know.

(Marking my own answer as correct in order to get this topic closed.)

EDIT: Have to wait for two days in order to mark this answer correct.

Comment: Your solution sounds fine. I would probably avoid the scriptlet by putting the calculation directly into the TextField. Use a commons lang utility(http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) replaceChars or just java.lang.String.replaceAll() a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks @mdahlman, I'll check the option of putting the calculation directly in the TextField.

Comment: What calculation did you use?

Comment: @Maxrunner I made this answer over 7 years ago, so I cannot remember any details of it unfortunately. By "calculation" I guess I meant "transformation" i.e. transforming the hyphens to non-breaking hyphens. I have no recollection of how Jasper Reports works, but I guess I must have made some code that will go through all the input data and replace hyphen with non-breaking hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Type in the Text field ''Expression'' like this:

```
String.join("\uFEFF", $F{field1}.split("(?!^)"))
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: It will insert "zero-width non-breaking space" between every single characters of the string.

Comment: will this work in bundle locale properties file? 
test.message = .......enviar\uFEFF-\uFEFFnos